# GTK# dialog closes immediately after Run()

Tags: macos, gtk, gtk#

I am new to MonoDevelop and GTK# on Mac OSX. I added a dialog to my project, and use the following code to display it from the main form:

```cs
    PatientAddDialog pd = new PatientAddDialog ();
    pd.SetPosition (WindowPosition.CenterOnParent);
    rc = pd.Run ();
    pd.Destroy ();
```

The dialog displays correctly, but no matter which button I click on, the dialog closes immediately, and returns to the main window. I first want to do some validation on the dialog, before closing it.

How must I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Destroy()` method on your dialog just after `Run()`, so that dialog window destroys itself and disappears.

Comment: Thank you, now the dialog is still visible, but control still returns to the main form after clicking on a button on the dialog.

Comment: @kenjutsu: create a new stackoverflow question